# URL rewriting with query strings not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my primary domain

`example.com`

mapped to a subdirectory named `example`.
I have used the method given at [this link](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347) for above.
The above .htaccess is in primary domain root folder.

Now I am using another .htaccess file to rewrite

`example.com/work/test.php?i=id&t=title`

as

`example.com/work/id/title`

so that the users only see the latter url instead of the former.
The id is of three digits and title may contain any character.

I have put this htaccess file in "work" folder in the `example` subdirectory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /work/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})(/)(.*)$ test.php?i=$1&t=$3 [L]
```

The page is not rendering as intended. Please help.

Comment: @arco444 Corrected in the question

Comment: I've just tested this and it works perfectly for me. Are your files definitely in the correct place? Are there any other RewriteRules that could be conflicting?

Comment: @arco444 I have just the above content in that htaccess. I have another htaccess for mapping the domain example.com to a subdirectory example. The work folder is in the example subdirectory.

Comment: I am using the method at [this link](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347) for the primary domain to subdirectory mapping

Comment: @RahilWazir I have two htaccess.
1. For mapping primary domain to a subdirectory. This is placed in primary domain folder
2. The one mentioned in the question. This is in work directory placed in the above subdirectory to which the primary domain is mapped.

Comment: @RahilWazir In work directory placed in the subdirectory to which the primary domain is mapped

Comment: @ashutoshagrawal1010 Can you please edit this to your question and please do clearly mention that what are your directory structures and where files are.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? If not, did you try escaping the `/` like this `\/`. Generally speaking, Apache web servers are complied with a Perl compatible regular expression engine (similar, if not the same as PHP). The `/` is the default delimiter in regular expressions. I would escape it just to be on the safe side. I see the QSA thing a lot, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need the QSA (query string append) Parameter:

```
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})(/)(.*)$ test.php?id=$1&title=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Don't think this is the case. The new query string is being explicitly defined in the rewrite and absence of query string params is unlikely to cause a 404 - more the page wouldn't display as intended.

Comment: @arco444 Rightly said, the page is not displayed as intended.